# How to pivot pandas dataframe on specific rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'recipe': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a','a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b','b'],
                   'product': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'A', 'B', 'G', 'I', 'K', 'F']})
```

And I want to pivot the dataframe for the output to have one row for each recipe and multiple columns for each product, ex:

```
recipe  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6
a       A   B   C   D   E   F
b       A   B   G   I   K   F
```

Also, there are multiple products, but I want the top 6 based on another column that gives a ranking for how relevant the product is

Comment: What code you tried so far?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy I tried using pivot, but it doesn't give me what I am looking for ... I'm playing around using metl and pivot but not luck yet

Comment: Maybe you will find something like this of help: ```pd.get_dummies(df, columns=["product"]).groupby("recipe").sum(min_count=1)```

Comment: @gorjan your code is interesting, but I have thousands of products names, and only want the top 10. Your method will not work. I also want the columns to be labeled product 1 - 10 and with the actual product names in the cells.

Comment: What do you mean by top 10?

Comment: @gorjan so I will have 100s of products matched to each recipe, and I only want the top n of these based on their another column called cos_score. I don't want 100s of product columns, I just want the top n products for each recipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a `groupby` and [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe) problem.

```
u = df.groupby('recipe')['product'].apply(list)
pd.DataFrame(u.tolist(), index=u.index).rename(lambda x: 'p{}'.format(x+1), axis=1)

       p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6
recipe                  
a       A  B  C  D  E  F
b       A  B  G  I  K  F
```